# C# Form UserControl OnClick events

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, onclick

I've created a custom user control for a windows form that will operate similar to a button (and please don't suggest that I just use a button, because I will be storing data in this user control), but I can't figure out how to get the `OnClick()` event to fire. I've sifted through a handful of tutorials and looked at a few similar questions on the site, but I can't seem to get the event to fire off - so I'm either doing something wrong or everyone posted incorrect code (I hope it isn't the latter)

In my custom control.cs,

```
namespace MobCreator {
    public partial class MOBSample : UserControl {
        public MOBSample() {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
           this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
           base.OnMouseUp(e);
        }
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
           this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
           base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }
        public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
        private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           // invoke UserControl event here
           if (this.ButtonClick != null) this.OnButtonClick(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my form.cs,

```
private void MobCreatorForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(this.CustomEvent_Handler);
}
private void CustomEvent_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Click");
}
```

However, when I run the program my console never outputs "Click".

Comment: OnButtonClick is handling the click in your UserForm of what control?. The problem must be that the click on your usercontrol never reaches private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: The code looks ok - the problem must be elsewhere. Just to be sure, if you set a breakpoint on your `Console.WriteLine(..)` and debug you code - it never reaches that breakpoint?

Comment: Correct, it never reaches the breakpoint.

Comment: You need to raise the button click on mousedown event.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): it is a simple Event tutorial, you should be able to adapt it to your scenario.

At a first look, what you are probably missing is a Delegate for your event.

Comment: He doesn't need a delegate. he is using EventHandler

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void MobCreatorForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomEvent_Handler(null,null);
}

private void CustomEvent_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Click");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to accomplish, other than displaying "Click" on the Console when the form loads?

Comment: Isn't this what you asked for ? you asked to fire event. you can replace Console.WriteLine("Click"); with your logic.